# When hibernate sets primary key(id)?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have this code:

```
Candidate candidate = new Candidate();
candidate.setName("testUser");
candidate.setPhone("88888");
candidateService.add(candidate);
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
return candidate;
```

CandidateService marked as `@Transactional`;

Can you explain me why after execution of `candidateService.add(candidate);`
candidate get id field value. 
Maybe it is normally?

```
candidateService.add(candidate) realization:

public void add(Candidate candidate) {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String login = auth.getName();
     User user =  utilService.getOrSaveUser(login);
     candidate.setAuthor(user);
     candidateDao.add(candidate);
}
```

---

```
@Override
public Integer add(Candidate candidate) throws HibernateException{
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    if (candidate == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Integer id = (Integer) session.save(candidate);
    return id;

}
```

I thought it happened if candidate in persistent state.

I messed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the ID is primary key of the table candiate,when you add it to database a Id generates and returned by the save method.

If you see docs of [save method](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#save%28java.lang.Object%29).

> Persist the given transient instance, first assigning a generated identifier. (Or using the current value of the identifier property if the assigned generator is used.) This operation cascades to associated instances if the association is mapped with cascade="save-update".
>
> Returns:
>   the generated identifier

Comment: What reason "Returns: the generated identifier" ? I can get id so: myEntity.getId();

Comment: Because that is the first time the record hit the DB and DB generated an Id for it.

Comment: yes,you can use setId(yourId) and then you have to save that entity again in DB. Until then It won't change. And exceptions are natural if the Id you provided already exists for another record.But that is not recommended.

Comment: @user2740224 Sorry I did'nt get you,`once But at once after execution these identificators are equal`  do you mean after the call of save,the both ID of entity and  database ?? If it so , of course same :)

Comment: sorry for my English)